# Huber-Loss optimisation using Stochastic Gradient Descent to estimate intercept and coefficient of regression line

Tags: regression, r, optimization, loss-functions, stochastic-gradient-descent

**What**: I'm trying to minimise the Huber-Loss for a linear regression using Stochastic Gradient Descent from scratch.
**Problem**: It seems like that the coeffcient $m$ doesn't get optimised, therefore the fitted line is nowhere near the OLS regression line which serves as reference.
**Expectation**: Optimised coefficient resulting in a fitted regression line close to the reference OLS regression line.
**Explanation**: The Huber-Loss is defined as
$$ L_{\delta}(a) = \begin{array}{l}\frac{1}{2}a^2 \quad \textrm{for} \quad \vert a \vert \leq \delta \\  
\delta (\vert a \vert - \frac{1}{2}\delta) \quad \textrm{otherwise} \end{array} $$

The variable $a$ refers to the residual $a = y - \hat{y}$, which means for linear regression: $a = y - (mx+n)$. To use Stochastic Gradient Descent, the partial derivatives with respect to the coefficient $m$ and the intercept $n$ have to be calculated:
$$\nabla L_{\delta}(m, n, y) = \left[\begin{array}{l}
\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial m} = \begin{array}{l} -x\ (-mx+n-y)\quad \textrm{for} \quad \vert y-(mx+n) \vert \leq \delta \\
\frac{\delta x(mx+n-y)}{\vert mx+n-y \vert} \quad \textrm{otherwise}
 \end{array}\\
\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial n} = \begin{array}{l} mx+n-y\quad \textrm{for} \quad \vert y-(mx+n) \vert \leq \delta \\
\frac{\delta (mx+n-y)}{\vert mx+n-y \vert} \quad \textrm{otherwise}
 \end{array} \\ 
\end{array}\right]$$
I implemented the above in R the following way.

```
grad_m_huber <- function(

    Y,
    X,
    m,
    n,
    delta

) {

    loss <- ifelse(
        abs(Y - (m * X + n)) <= delta,
        -X * (-m * X - n + Y),
        (delta * X * (m * X + n - Y)) / abs(n + m * X - Y)
    )

    return(loss)

}


grad_n_huber <- function(

    Y,
    X,
    m,
    n,
    delta

) {

    loss <- ifelse(
        abs((m * X + n) - Y) <= delta,
        m * X + n - Y,
        (delta * (m * X + n - Y)) / abs(m * X + n - Y)
    )

    return(loss)

}


huber_sgd <- function(

    X,
    Y,
    epochs,
    lr,
    batch_size,
    delta

) {

    m <- 0
    n <- 0

    for(i in 1:epochs) {

        batch <- sample(length(X), batch_size)
        Y_batch <- Y[batch]
        X_batch <- X[batch]

        g_m <- sum(grad_m_huber(Y_batch, X_batch, m, n, delta))
        g_n <- sum(grad_n_huber(Y_batch, X_batch, m, n, delta))

        m <- m - lr * g_m
        n <- n - lr * g_n

    }

    return(
        list(
            grad_m = g_m,
            grad_n = g_n,
            m = m,
            n = n
        )
    )

}
```

But when I run the Huber-Loss regression with a delta close to 0, which should result in a fitting line close to a linear regression (`ols_mod <- lm(Y ~ X)`):

```
set.seed(303)
Y <- rnorm(550, 155, 15)
scale_factor <- .27
eps <- rnorm(550, 15, 5)

X <- (Y * scale_factor) + eps

huber_sgd_mod <- huber_sgd(
    X,
    Y,
    epochs = 5000,
    epsillon = .001,
    batch_size = 1,
    delta = .01
)
```

I get
[image: Huber-Loss Regression vs. OLS Regression with 5000 epochs]
As the plotted loss indicated that SGD didn't converge yet I changed the number of epochs to `epochs = 10000` and ran it again. It seems like that only the intercept gets optimised.
[image: Huber-Loss Regression vs. OLS Regression with 10000 epochs]
I also compared my *from scratch solution* to a Huber-Regression calculated by `MASS::rlm(Y ~ X, psi = MASS::psi.huber)` which shows the expected fitted line close to the OLS regression line.
[image: Huber-Loss Regression with 10000 epochs vs. OLS Regression vs. MASS::rlm()]
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The partial derivatives you wrote down don't match the ones in your R code. You probably have some typos somewhere.